# Getting data from other file out of thread python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, flask

I want to run a thread to get data, store that data in a variable, and then serve that variable with Flask (web page). Right now, the webserver serves a variable only containing the things I added with `create_sock` and not the ones added with `update_data`.

`sock.py` (puts data in variable)

```py
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread
import time
import json

import config
import sock_data


class ServerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, serv_id, host, port):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.serv_id = serv_id
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def run(self):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
            sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
            while True:
                sock.sendall(b'info')
                data = sock.recv(1024)
                if data:
                    new_data = data.decode('utf-8')
                    new_data = json.loads(new_data)
                    sock_data.update_data(self.serv_id, new_data)
                time.sleep(config.NEW_DATA_DELAY)
```

`sock_data.py` (manages variable with handy methods)

```py
sock_list = []

def create_sock(name):
    sock_id = len(sock_list)
    sock_list.append({
        "sock_id": sock_id,
        "name": name,
    })
    return sock_id

def update_data(sock_id, data):
    sock_list[sock_id].update(data)
    print(sock_list)

def get_all():
    print(sock_list)
    return sock_list
```

`webserver.py` (serves variable as json on web)

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import threading

import sock

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def route_test():
    return "Working"

@app.route("/getservers")
def route_servers():
    return jsonify(sock_data.get_all())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the thread inside webserver.py.

```
server_thread = ServerThread()
server_thread.start()
```

These are some things you must take care: The first is using `sock_list` as a list and then as a dict. Your function `update_data` will probably throw KeyError when called inside `ServerThread`. Also, you must be careful with racing conditions, that can occur if `create_sock` and `update_data` are called simultaneously.